# How can I avoid xaml warnings when a binding is null in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my WPF app I have a style that fills a rectangle with an image brush when the bound object is not null. The style works the way I would expect but, I get warnings about the ImageBrush setter value when the Binding is null. I was hoping I could avoid this using a converter or a null trigger but, I still get the warning. Is there a way in which I can bind to an object and check if its null in xaml without getting a warning in the output window?

```
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle" x:Key="LightHeadRectangle">
            <Setter  Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BarLight, Converter={StaticResource isNullConverter}}" Value="false">
                    <Setter  Property="Fill">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="{Binding BarLight.OpenMount.ImagePath}" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>​
```

Update: Looking to stop generic null warnings from occurring, but the specific warning I get in this case is.

System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=BarLight.OpenMount.ImagePath; DataItem=null; target element is 'ImageBrush' (HashCode=47952502); target property is 'ImageSource' (type 'ImageSource')

Update:

It may be helpful to note, that I am using this style to target multiple listboxitem data templates. Also BarLight, is initially null.

Comment: What warning do you get?

Comment: aren't you also binding to BarLight.OpenMount though, where BarLight can be null, therefore trying to get .OpenMount from a null is a problem?

Comment: Throw a `TargetNullValue` or a `FallbackValue` in your binding base to handle it.

Comment: @TheodosiusVonRichthofen Yes but even when the logic returns true it still throughs a warning for the ImageBrush setter, which is not hit in that case.

Comment: @ChrisW. I added TargetNullValue='my uri' but it still throws the warning

Comment: I'm afraid it can only be achieved with converter, where you will check all steps for null value. Hope there's better answer

Comment: Try FallbackValue then, one of them should clear it up.

Comment: @ChrisW. Nope, neither method stops the warning message.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK you cannot turn them off in code, but if you're using Visual Studio, you can turn them off in there.

1. Go to Tools -> Options
2. Under Debugging (on the left pane), go to Output Window
3. Under WPF Trace Settings (on the right pane), find Data Binding and set it's value to Off

That being said, it's perfectly acceptable for bindings to silently fail in XAML. A failed binding does not throw an exception, so it has no end user impact (as long as you, the developer, meant for the binding to fail in some cases where the user's *experience* isn't compromised).

The warning is there just as a debugging mechanism for developers in case they don't expect the binding to fail. I wouldn't recommend turning this off.

Comment: That said, it would be really nice if WPF provided a mechanism to say "I expect this specific binding may sometimes will fail and I don't want to be warned about that". I'd rather have *any* BindingExpression warning that appears in the Output pane as being something to investigate & remedy, rather than accepting that this will be a non-empty list that I have to comb through to determine which is a problem and which is not.

Comment: Never advice anyone to turn WPF debugging warnings in IDE, for his (or her) own good.

Comment: @yatskovsky I think you mean "turn _off_" warnings in the IDE

Comment: Sure, 'turn off'. Thanks.

Comment: @yatskovsky You clearly didn't read the full answer, because the last line in my answer says "I wouldn't recommend turning this off."

Answer (score 1):

Put your ImageBrush in a separate resource will solve the issue.

```
    <ImageBrush x:Key="brush" Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="{Binding BarLight.OpenMount.ImagePath}" />
    <Style TargetType="Rectangle" x:Key="LightHeadRectangle">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BarLight, Converter={StaticResource isNullConverter}}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource brush}">
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: This simply moves the null error from the template that the style is applied on , to the datacontext backing the entire view.